How to correct Dolby Vision HDR video on Windows 10 (it is correct after sharing on Facebook)
I have a video that is recorded from an iPhone in Dolby Vision HDR. When playing it using the Windows Films & TV app, the colours look washed out (I assume it is because Windows does not have native Dolby Vision support?)
When I upload the same video to Facebook, the colours look correct.

I assume this is because Facebook must have some kind of tone mapping as part of the video processing pipeline?
How do I get the corrected colours in Windows 10? The colours obviously exist (as I can see them on the facebook version of the video).

Left is screenshot from Films & TV, right is same frame from video after it has been uploaded to Facebook.


I'm pretty certain that facebook transcodes uploaded video so that it is playable through their software, uses codecs they have licensed, and is compressed to the degree they want, since they;ll have to store it.

Note that HDR of whatever flavor requires specific hardware compatibility, at the video card, the os, and the display.  everything has to line up or it won't work. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/display-requirements-for-hdr-video-in-windows-192f362e-1245-e14d-3d3f-4b3fc606b80f Windows also only natively supports HD10/HD10P HDR, not DolbyVision.  there is some discussion on the evolution of windows support for DV here: https://www.reddit.com/r/htpc/comments/1936n8g/dolby_vision_lldv_now_possible_on_windows_1011/
